# Integration with Active Directory as a native Windows client?

Tags: asp.net, .net, active-directory, ldap

I'm working with a requirements specification and trying to understand one of their requirements:

"Integration with Active Directory should be done as a native Windows client and not as an LDAP-application".

Is there a particular API, protocol or similar that "as a native Windows client" is most likely to refer to? Something like Kerberos etc?

I believe the requirement is stated in the context of authenticating users that present their username/password in a web GUI, and the web application should verify their details with an AD domain controller.

If there is some API or protocol that is most likely for this scenario, a simple example or code pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What Kind of App? Web or desktop ?

Comment: *What I understand with that requirement* is that your application should automatically pick up the logged in user credentials to be able to use application feature. The **LDAP application** will ask user to provide their credentials and then will be able to verify to allow use of features.

Comment: @VikramSaini That is a theory, but it is somewhat contradicted by them having separate requirements for SSO, and also indications that you should be able to logon also without SSO.

Comment: @OskarBerggren Well! In that case, I don't have a clue. However when in doubt ask client. I had suffered lot in past for making assumptions out of requirement and in end client will state something else opposite. *So better to ask them.*

Comment: Like Vikram said: ask your client what his demand means. Even if we guess right he could mean something different

Comment: Well, public tenders are not always clear and unfortunately the time limit for questions have expired before I found this. I was hoping that this requirement would turn out to be reasonably obvious to someone more accustomed to Windows/AD authentication.

Comment: Usually I find they are really looking for using The GSS-SPNEGO authentication mechanism (RFC4178) is actually the GSSAPI authentication mechanism but with a client-server negotiation mechanism that provides for selection of the preferred security mechanism that both client and server support. In this case, the server will prefer Kerberos then NTLMv2 then NTLM (UWWI does not support LM). For that reason, refer to the GSSAPI authentication mechanism for further details. This allows a browser based application to use "Windows" credentials to authenticate to LDAP/Microsoft Active Directory.